# Continuity of a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis, continuity

> Let $$f\left(z\right)=\left(\frac{1}{z}-\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(\frac{1}{z-2}\right).$$
>   Define the function at $z=2$ so it will be continuous there.

So we have to find the limit of the function at the point and set the value of the function at $z=2$ to be the the limit

$$\lim_{z\to 2}\left(\frac{1}{z}-\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(\frac{1}{z-2}\right)=\lim_{z\to 2}\left(\frac{2-z}{2z}\right)\left(\frac{1}{z-2}\right)=\lim_{z\to 2}\frac{-\left(z-2\right)}{2z\left(z-2\right)}=\lim_{z\to 2}\frac{-1}{2z}=-\frac{1}{4}.$$

So $f\left(2\right)=-\frac{1}{4}.$

Is it correct to look at it as a real function? As we are looking at $z=x+yi$ where $z\to 2$ which is $x+yi\to 2+0i$?

Comment: Yes that's fine.

Comment: Personally, just let $f(z)=-\frac12z^{-1}$.  =P

Comment: You did it right.